# How can I handle the base case of this recursive function? My base case is causing an output of zero

Tags: python-3.x

```
''' Returns number of pennies if pennies are doubled num_days times'''
def double_pennies(num_pennies, num_days):
    total_pennies = 0

    if num_days == 0:
        return total_pennies

    else:
        total_pennies = double_pennies((num_pennies * 2), (num_days - 1));

    return total_pennies

''' Program computes pennies if you have 1 penny today,'''
''' 2 pennies after one day, 4 after two days, and so on'''
starting_pennies = 1
user_days = 10

print('Number of pennies after', user_days, 'days: ', end="")
print(double_pennies(starting_pennies, user_days))
```

Comment: If you have 1 penny, and you double it 0 times, how many pennies do you have?

Comment: @trentcl, if I have 1 penny and double it by zero times then the result is zero pennies.

Comment: Then the algorithm is correct. But if zero isn't the result you want, you might want to think about that question a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

This base case worked for me

```
if num_days == 0:
    total_pennies = num_pennies
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an elif like so :-

```
total_pennies = num_pennies

if num_days == 0:
    return total_pennies    # or if you want return 0
elif (num_days == 1):
    return total_pennies * 2
else:
    total_pennies = double_pennies((num_pennies * 2), (num_days - 1));

return total_pennies
```

Its instructive to understand what a base case means. A base case doesnt mean that there is only one condition when the recusion should terminate; instead it means that it is one of the possible conditions when the reecusion should terminate.

With that you can see that your problem has two base-cases.

1. When 0 days have passed, you have no money
2. When 1 day has passed, you have double the input money.
3. When any more number of days have passed, you have as much money as double the previous day.

So you see that to code the above 3 cases, you need an if - elif -else.

Comment: The question was poorly formatted when I answered it. It seemed to me that he wanted the 0-day case to be a `return 0`.

Comment: Even with a nonzero number of days your first suggestion still returns zero all the time. Probably you meant `num_pennies*2`

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your base case is incorrect. You don't have zero pennies after zero days -- you have exactly what you started with.

- Start with 1 penny. Double it 3 times. You have 1*2*2*2 = 8 pennies.
- Start with 1 penny. Double it 2 times. You have 1*2*2 = 4 pennies.
- Start with 1 penny. Double it 1 time. You have 1*2 = 2 pennies.
- Start with 1 penny. Double it 0 times. You have 1 penny.

Your base case should be merely

```
if num_days == 0:
    return num_pennies
```

There is no need to initialize `total_pennies` to 0, or at all, really.

Comment: Your solution and @luckuguy73 solutions are entirely the same. If num_days is 0 aka the base case, you return 0. While luckyguy73's solution sets total_pennies equal to the base case which again is 0. Both solutions are the exact same which is why they both pass all tests.

Answer (score 0):

Only this if statement worked for me:

```
 if(num_pennies == 1):
    total_pennies = 2**num_days
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
if (numDays == 0)

 totalPennies = numPennies;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Returns number of pennies if pennies are doubled num_days times
def double_pennies(num_pennies, num_days):
    total_pennies = 0

    if num_days == 0:
        total_pennies = num_pennies
    elif (num_days == 1):
        total_pennies = total_pennies + (num_pennies * 2)
    else:
        total_pennies = double_pennies((num_pennies * 2), (num_days - 1))

    return total_pennies

# Program computes pennies if you have 1 penny today,
# 2 pennies after one day, 4 after two days, and so on
starting_pennies = 1
user_days = 10

print('Number of pennies after', user_days, 'days: ', end="")
print(double_pennies(starting_pennies, user_days))
```